# Why is my console is say NaN is class extend Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I was making project and when I try to get the parameter from class parent its say `NaN` while the other is `true`.
Here the code:

```js
class transportasi {//class parent
  constructor(nama,roda,pintu){
  this.nama = nama
  this.roda = roda
  this.pintu = pintu

  }
}

class mobil extends transportasi{//Class Children
  constructor(roda,lampu){
    super(roda)//the problem
    this.lampu = lampu
  }

  jmlahfeature(){
    return this.lampu + this.roda 
  }
}
const mobil1 = new mobil(2,4)//the problem

//I cant fill the value of roda only lampu
console.log("Hasil Perhitungan Feature mobil : " + mobil1.jmlahfeature())
```

I want it so I can fill the value of parameter `roda`. So it doesn't say `NaN` in console.

Comment: `roda` is the second parameter of the `transportasi` constructor. You only pass 1 parameter to `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivar points out correctly roda is the second parameter and you pass only the first parameter in the super().

The following code should give your desired result.

```
class transportasi {//class parent
    constructor(nama,roda,pintu){
    this.nama = nama
    this.roda = roda
    this.pintu = pintu
    
    }
}

class mobil extends transportasi{//Class Children
    constructor(roda,lampu){
        super('here should be some value', roda) 
        this.lampu = lampu
    }
    
    jmlahfeature(){
        return this.lampu + this.roda 
    }
}
const mobil1 = new mobil(2,4)//the problem

//I cant fill the value of roda only lampu
console.log("Hasil Perhitungan Feature mobil : " + mobil1.jmlahfeature())
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign any value to `this.roda = roda`
You can try this out.

```
class transportasi {//class parent
    constructor(nama,roda,pintu){
    this.nama = nama
    this.roda = roda
    this.pintu = pintu
  
    }
  }
  
  class mobil extends transportasi{//Class Children
    constructor(roda,lampu){
      super(roda)//the problem
      this.roda = roda
      this.lampu = lampu
    }
  
    jmlahfeature(){
      return this.lampu + this.roda 
    }
  }
  const mobil1 = new mobil(2,4)//the problem
  
  //I cant fill the value of roda only lampu
  console.log("Hasil Perhitungan Feature mobil : " + mobil1.jmlahfeature())
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than individual arguments for the parent and child classes you supply a single object with named properties. A simple test within the child class can assign a default value if the required property has not been assigned to the parent arguments.

```js
class transportasi {
  constructor(args = {}) {
    args = Object.assign({
      nama: false,
      roda: false,
      pintu: false
    }, args);

    this.nama = args.nama;
    this.roda = args.roda;
    this.pintu = args.pintu;
  }
}

class mobil extends transportasi {
  constructor(args = {}) {
    super(args)
    this.lampu = args.lampu || 0;
  }
  jmlahfeature() {
    return this.lampu + this.roda
  }
}


/* correctly named property - Maths should succeed */
const args = {
  lampu: 2,
  roda: 4
};
const app1 = new mobil(args);
console.log(app1.jmlahfeature());

/* incorrectly named, default value of zero used */
const bogus = {
  xlamxpu: 23,
  roda: 33
}
const app2 = new mobil(bogus);
console.log(app2.jmlahfeature());
```